# Доступ к массиву из другого класса java

Tags: java

хочу сделать так, чтобы при вызове метода из другого класса можно было менять значение его массива на нужное мне, но никак не выходит это сделать через сеттер
вот есть массив

```
public static String ae[][] = new String[11][11];
```

нужно как-то его изменить из другого класса, если геттер:

```
public String[][] getField() {
    field();
    return ae;
}
```

Comment: что такое field()?

Comment: Не выходит сделать через сеттер, а в вопросе почему-то геттер.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```
public void setField(String[][] newArray) {
    ae = newArray;
}
```

Или, если вы хотите изменять, только конкретную ячейку массива:

```
public void setField(int i, int j, String newValue) {
    ae[i][j] = newValue;
}
```